# Constructors for Arrays and Binary Trees

Tags: c++

I'm making a binary tree using STD vector. I've pared it down significantly, but the general idea is below:

```
template <class DataType>
class ArrayNode
{
protected:
    DataType* _info;
    int _left; //index position of left node
    int _right;//index position of right node

public:
    ArrayNode(const DataType& info, int left, int right);
    virtual ~ArrayNode();
    DataType& getInfo();
}

template <class DataType>
class ArrayBinaryTree
{
protected:
    vector<ArrayNode<DataType>* >* theBinaryTree;
    int _root;
    int _numOfNodes;
    int _size; 
    //etc.
public:
    ArrayBinaryTree(DataType info);
    virtual ~ArrayBinaryTree();
}
```

How would you create a constructor so that you could access the nodes with `getInfo()`? My idea was to do this:

```
std::vector<ArrayNode<DataType>*> binaryTree(1);

ArrayBTNode<DataType>* element = new ArrayNode<DataType>(info, -1, -1); //some generic data
binaryTree.insert(binaryTree.begin(), 1, element);
theBinaryTree = &binaryTree;
```

And then access with something like `(*theBinaryTree->at(0)).getInfo()`.
However, with this type of constructor, the `getInfo()` returns `null`. What would be a better way to set up the constructor for accessing?

Comment: you are taking an address of vector which is destroyed at the end of function.

Comment: So many pointers. Why so many pointers? (I have a terrible feeling that `ArrayNode:: ArrayNode` says `_info  = &info;`, too.)

Comment: all that `*`s make me dizzy

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to make a tree structure using a vector/array. Especially not a binary tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me change interface a bit because I don't see the point of having vector saved as pointer. Same goes for data stored in vector and for data in node:

```
template <class DataType>
class ArrayNode
{
protected:
    DataType _info;
    // ... rest of ArrayNode interface
}

template <class DataType>
class ArrayBinaryTree {
protected:
    vector<ArrayNode<DataType> > theBinaryTree; // not pointers anymore
    int _root = -1; // something that tells you no values are present
    // You need size and numOfNodes attributes
    // You get both of these things by calling size() method of std::vector
    // etc.
public:
    ArrayBinaryTree(DataType info);
    virtual ~ArrayBinaryTree();
}
```

Constructor the can be implemented e.g. like this (assuming it initializes root Node):

```
ArrayBinaryTree(DataType info) {
    theBinaryTree.push_back(ArrayNode<DataType>(info, -1, -1));
    _root = 0;
}
```

Or even better, you can use initialization list:

```
 ArrayBinaryTree(DataType info)
       : theBinaryTree( { ArrayNode<DataType>(info, -1, -1) } ),
         _root(0) {}
```

I don't know if you have to implement it through vector or if it was just your design choice. If it was just your design choice I would recommend redesigning it. Assume this simplified interface:

```
template< typename T >
struct Node {
    T _value;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> _right;

    Node(const T& val) : _value(val) {}
};

template < typename T >
class BinTree {
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> _root;
public:
    // methods
};
```

I find this design much better for structures like trees. If you are interested I can write a bit more.
NOTE: std::unique_ptr was introduced in c++11, so if you write in older standard raw pointers will have to do (= bit more work).